# Guess the number game - want to give users hints but the code doesn't work

Tags: python

`x` is a random number between 1 and 10 and users have to guess it. Basically, I want to give them hints, but the code doesn't work.

```
print("Hint:")
if guess == x/2 == int :
    print("The target number is even.")
if guess == x/2 == float :
    print("The target number is uneven.")
```

Comment: Sorry, but `"the code doesn't work"` is not a symptom. Do you have any errors? Does the code output something you didn't expect?

Comment: `guess == x/2 == int` makes absolutely no sense at all. That's equivalent to `guess == x/2 and x/2 == int`, but neither of those comparisons is something you want to do. `x/2 == int` can never be true, I guess you meant `type(x/2) == int`

Comment: But `type(x/2)` will never be `int`. Even when `x` is even, `x/2` is a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead use modulus operator to check if it's even or odd:

```
if x % 2 == 0:
    print("Even")
else:
    print("Odd")
```

Using it returns the remainder of the division.

- `9 % 3` → `0`
- `10 % 3` → `1`
- `10 % 4` → `2`
- `12 % 4` → `0`

So if remainder is `0`, it is divisible by that number.

Answer (score 0):

To check the oddness/evenness of a number, you should use the modulus operator. You shouldn't attempt to directly typecheck the result of the division:

```py
guess = 1
print("Hint:")
if guess % 2 == 0 :
    print("The target number is even.")
else:
    print("The target number is odd.")
```